# Dice Emulation - onClickListener in loop

Tags: java, android, loops, onclick

I'm working on Yahtzee program for a mobile app class, and running into some trouble.  The loop that I have written will run through the loop (13 turns and 3 rolls) even when the onClick() is only pressed once. I have moved them into several different orders but I can't seem to get it right.  Could someone guide me in the right direction to have the onClick accurately keep tally of the turns and rolls?

**Code**

```
import java.util.Random;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;



public class Yahtzee4Activity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */


    ImageButton dice1, dice2, dice3, dice4, dice5;
    Button roll, begin;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main); 
        PlayGame();        
    }

    public void PlayGame()  
    {  
        final Random rand = new Random(); 

        final int MAX_TURNS = 13;
        final int MAX_ROLLS = 3;


        dice1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btndice1);  
        dice2 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btndice2); 
        dice3 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btndice3); 
        dice4 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btndice4); 
        dice5 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btndice5);

        final ImageButton[] dice = {dice1, dice2, dice3, dice4, dice5}; //array of buttons (dice)
        final int [] diceValue = new int [5];
        final boolean [] isHeld = {false, false, false, false, false};  // array of dice to be held (hold)



        roll = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnroll);
        begin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnbegin);        

        roll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v ) {   
                RollDice(dice, diceValue, isHeld, rand);    
            }
        });

        int turnNum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_TURNS; i++) {

            int rollNum = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < MAX_ROLLS; j++) {                   
                rollNum++;
                roll.setText("Roll (" + (MAX_ROLLS - rollNum) + " Remaining)");
            }
            turnNum++;      
            ScoreDice();                
        }  
    }

    private void ScoreDice() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public int[] RollDice(ImageButton [] dice, int [] diceValue, boolean [] isHeld, Random rand)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dice.length; i++) {
            if (!isHeld[i]) {
                int rndInt = rand.nextInt(6) + 1; // Random number between 1 and 6          
                String imgName = "die" + rndInt;                    
                int id = getResources().getIdentifier(imgName, "drawable", getPackageName());   
                diceValue[i] = rndInt;
                dice[i].setImageResource(id);  //Loops through the dice array and sets the appropriate dice images based on individual randoms
            } else {
                //do nothing                        
            }
        }
        return diceValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just looping through all the rolls and turns because you don't tell it to do otherwise. I would suggest moving most of your code to RollDice(...). In order for the below example to work, you will need to make rollNum, turnNum, MAX_TURNS, MAX_ROLLS instance variables instead of local variable eg:

```
ImageButton dice1,dice2,dice3,dice4,dice5;
Button roll, begin;
private final int MAX_TURNS = 13;
private final int MAX_ROLLS = 3;
private int turnNum = 0;
private int rollNum = 0;
```

And then remove the turn code from PlayGame and put it in RollDice like so:

```
public int[] RollDice(ImageButton [] dice, int [] diceValue, boolean [] isHeld, Random rand)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dice.length; i++) {
        if (!isHeld[i]) {
            int rndInt = rand.nextInt(6) + 1; // Random number between 1 and 6          
            String imgName = "die" + rndInt;                    
            int id = getResources().getIdentifier(imgName, "drawable", getPackageName());   
            diceValue[i] = rndInt;
            dice[i].setImageResource(id);  //Loops through the dice array and sets the appropriate dice images based on individual randoms
        } else {
            //do nothing                        
        }
    }

    rollNum ++;
    if(rollNum >= MAX_ROLLS){
        //Turn is over
        turnNum ++;
        ScoreDice();
    else {
        roll.setText("Roll (" + (MAX_ROLLS - rollNum) + " Remaining)");
    }

    return diceValue;
}
```

I think its worth pointing out also that your java code style could do with some brushing up, for example it is generally accepted that class names should start with an upper case letter and method names with a lower case letter things like that. Completely up to you of coarse, but good habits when you are beginning will help further down the track if you start collaborating with other programmers

Comment: Thank you for the help, I was put into this class without any previous java experience, I've only done c++.

Comment: Is this what you meant by instance variables? I moved them to the top of my application:

`public class Yahtzee4Activity extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

 
     ImageButton dice1, dice2, dice3, dice4, dice5;

     Button roll, begin;

     private final int MAX_TURNS = 13;

  private final int MAX_ROLLS = 3;

  private int turnNum = 0;

  private int rollNum = 0;

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main); 

        playGame();     
   
    }`

Comment: I took a mobile class with only having C++ experience. You should be fine. It's all classes. Your previous comment looks like a start in the right direction.

Comment: Yes, exactly what I meant by instance variables.